# Oracle ATG BCC Deployment

Tags: jboss, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet, atg-dust

How to deploy an Html content to BCC server in Oracle ATG?

I need to deploy the Html page from my Bcc, so it gets reflected in my production server. I am new to ATG, so i don't know how to start with the basic scratch work.

Things i have started as  a scratch.

1. Created the ATG project in the Eclipse and deployed to the JBOSS.
2. Created the database and accessed through the Repository.
3. Created the versioned repository and dono how to accesses it through the BCC.
   After these steps, i got struck up. Is the following steps are correct for starting the ATG as a Beginner?
   please give me a good suggestion or the task to learn the ATG from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCC out of the box don't have the capability to create web pages (don't confuse it with multisite feature). Some time ago ATG was integrated with Endeca which can create pages using Expirience Manager. Now usually you will buy a bundle ATG11 + Endeca.

You have few alternatives to that, usually paid extensions. First is using ATG Sitebuilder plugin delivered by a company called Spindrift. It extend BCC and gives you possibility to build pages from blocks. 
Next paid is APF (ATG Portal Framework) from company AMG.net, it gives you possibility to manage pages and content of those pages with nice live editing tool.
Other solution is to create dedicated repository with HTML spinets and use simple ootb droplet (e.g. RepositoryLookup) to show that content.